# query returns no results-Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

What I am trying to do is create a table contains intersections at the location where each road intersects `Roadname 1 & Roadname 2` as well as the geometry spatial data for the intersection `ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)`

But it  seems it doesn't work out l. I am pretty new to postgres, and I am wondering if there is a way to do so? The following is what I have so far.

```
Create Table roads(
    intid_ integer,
    muni text,
    alias_ text,
    roadnames text,
    geom geometry);

Insert into roads (roadnames, geom, intid_, alias_)
SELECT 
    trim(student.sc_e911slrn.prefix) || trim(student.sc_e911slrn.name) || trim(student.sc_e911slrn.suffix), 
    geom, objectid, alias
FROM student.sc_e911slrn;

--------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE type student.inter AS (
     roadnames text,
        intid_ int,
        alias_ text,
        muni text,
        ST_Intersection geometry,
        geom geometry);

--< Cursor >--------------------------------------------------------
Create function create_intersections()
    /*returns table student.intersect_roads As $method1$*/
    RETURNS table (
        roadnames text,
        intid_ int,
        alias_ text,
        muni text,
        ST_Intersection geometry,
        geom geometry) As $$

Declare
    return_intersect inter;
    rec_road Record;
    cur_road Cursor()
        For Select intid_, geom, roadnames
        From student.roads;

Begin
    Open cur_road();

    Loop
        fetch cur_road into rec_road;
        exit when not found;

        If ST_Touches(rec_road.geom, student.roads.geom) AND
            rec_road.geom != student.roads.geom AND 
            rec_road.intid_ != student.roads.intid_

        Then Update student.intersect_road
             Set st_intersection = ST_Intersection (rec_road.geom, student.roads.geom),
                 intid_ = rec_road.intid_,
                 intersections = rec_road.roadnames|| ' & ' || student.raods.roadnames,
                 alias_ = rec_road.alias_,
                 /*muni = */
                 polyline = ST_Union(rec_road.geom, student.roads.geom)
                 RETURNING * into return_intersect;
                 RETURN NEXT;
        End if;
    End Loop;
    Close cur_road;

    RETURN;

End; 
$$ Language plpgsql;

--< return the table>----------------------------------------------
SELECT create_intersections();
```

The `Roadname 1 & Roadname 2` should be generated from `roadnames` column from `ROADS` table, and the geometry for the intersection `ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)` should be generated from the `geom` column from `ROADS` table.
When I run it, it returns [no result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8cEn.png).

The table ROADS is something like this [road table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igJ8o.png),([geometry view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEcGD.png)):

```
Intid_     Muni    Alias_           Roadnames            geom
24581722   NULL    CR 52       Coopers Falls road        ...
24581723   NULL    CR 44       Rama road                 ...
```

Expected output should be similar to this one, but we need other fields to be filled as well.--->[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSEBW.png) ([geometry view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3jtF.png))

I also tried

```
CREATE FUNCTION create_intersections() 
     UPDATE student.intersect_roads AS $$
Declare
Begin
End
$$
```

Which is not working as well.
Any feedbacks would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kristie, welcome to SO! Could you elaborate more on the use case itself? I'm still not convinced you need `plpgsql` for that, but I need more information to be sure: 1) sample data and 2) exact expected result. Keep in mind that PostGIS questions containing graphical explanation are more likely to be answered ;) e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460941/postgis-st-within-didnt-do-what-i-want-how-to-find-a-point-in-a-hollow-area Cheers!

Comment: Hi @JimJones, thanks for your reply. I am trying to create a table that associated all the road intersections `roadname 1 & roadname 2` with its their geom, which can be applied in the searching function of our open source map page (the corresponding point feature will be returned on the map when we enter the `roadname`). But now, I am focusing on creating tables. I just updated the sample data in the original question:)

Comment: Just fixed the missing front clause error, now the query returns no results.